# How can I check these double Regex

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, string, validation

I want to check if a phone number has 8 digits and doesn't start with zero. I used this pattern `^[1-9][0-9]{7}` for this purpose, also I wanna check that these 8 numbers are not duplicated completely like `11111111` or `77777777`, for which I use this pattern: `(\w)\1{7,}`, separately to check that the number doesn't match with it.

Now I want to combine these Regex patterns together but I can't. I try to combine these patterns in this way:
`(?=([1-9][0-9]{7}))(?:(?!(\w1{7,})))` but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Note that I have to use one Regex pattern and need to combine these two patterns into one.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's only the first character you need to check, it looks like - capture it in a group, then use negative lookahead for that group repeated 7 times, to ensure that the entire string is not all the same number, then finish with `\d{7}` to match the other 7 digits:

```
^([1-9])(?!\1{7})\d{7}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/DbTtAJ/1

(note that `[0-9]` simplifies to `\d`)